# putFile command is not working

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi

I follow this [link](http://in.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/raspberrypiio/examples/getting-started-with-matlab-support-package-for-raspberry-pi-hardware.html) to transfer file to raspberry pi hardware. it works well while i sending image. but if i send text file it gives an error. how can i solve this?

```
  mypi = raspi;
  putFile(mypi,'output.txt','/home/pi/output.txt');
```

"Error executing command: pscp: output.txt: Cannot open file"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 fid=fopen('output.txt','w');
 fprintf(fid,'%s','hi');
 fclose(fid);

 mypi = raspi;
 putFile(mypi,'output.txt','/home/pi/output.txt');
```

Before I used fclose after pufile command. now this code is working